# How to define lmfit model for complex functions?

Tags: curve-fitting, curve, model-fitting, lmfit

I am working on cole cole model which basically exhibits how the permittivity varies with respect to frequency and is given by;

[image]

Where, ε_∞ is the higher permittivity,
ε_s is the static permittivity ε_s>ε_∞,
ε_(o) is 8.854e-12,

ω=2πf,

α is the relaxation time 0≪α≪1
σ is the conductivity (can be a CONSTANT)
I tried one of the examples given here https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/example_complex_resonator_model.html  but was not able to follow along.
Currently I have frequency vs real permittivity data. I want to fit the model to my measured data by using lmfit and guess the values from the fit. Basically i want to fit the real part of permittivity to the model.

Comment: @kaushai please post **actual code** of what you have tried.  Start by writing a "model function" to calculate epsilon as a function of omega and the parameters you want to fit (alpha, sigma, epsilon_s, epsilon_inf, etc) and then testing that it does what you think it should do....

Comment: This is a wide question. People working in the field of imperfect dielectics (non-Debye) know how arduous is the modelisation problem. They are a few pages in this paper : "A number of models for CPA impedances of conductors and for relaxation in non-Debye dielectrics" https://fr.scribd.com/doc/71923015/The-Phasance-Concept , pages 14-18. But this doesn't answer to your question because the methods of calculus of the parameters of the complex equation are not detailed in this paper. .

Comment: I doubt that the stackoverflow forum is the good place for this question. May be a better place would be either in a purely mathematical forum or in a physics forum. In order to make the question more concret, you  should joint  an example of data (real and imaginary parts of the permitivity at various frequencies on numerical form, not graph)  to make it more concrete.